# Run scheduled task on demand from ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks, impersonation

I'd like to run an application from a trusted intranet site. I'd like to run the application as a certain user, not the IIS user. I tried an approach using impersonation, but it looks like ASP.NET doesn't let you spin off a real process as a totally different user.

I was wondering if I could instead set up a scheduled task with the saved credentials of the user I want to run this application as, and then run the task on demand from ASP.NET?

Comment: there are many ways to solve this:  you could write a windows service which performs the operation you need to run as a different user.  The ASP could message the service and pass it params.

Comment: @developer Yes, I've used that approach in the past. But in this case I have a simple console application that I want to run, and I'd rather not turn it into a service that runs all the time.